setFullScreenIntent not working when screen is locked
I found out for new android versions we can't start a activity from background. So there is "setFullScreenIntent" which we can use if we want to show full screen activity from background service. I have studied everything related to it and also implemented but I can't make it work. As I see my activity onCreate log but also also see the onDestroy log as well. So need help form any of you guys for solving this problem.
I have added the required permissions in my manifest and also have asked the required runtime permmissions as well.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />

Function for setting the Notification
public static void showNotificationWithFullScreenIntent(Context context,
                                                            AlarmModel alarmModel) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getPackageName())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Message Alarm")
                .setContentText("Your new important message is here")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL) // Important for full-screen intent
                .setFullScreenIntent(getFullScreenIntent(context, alarmModel), true)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (notificationManager != null) {
            buildChannel(notificationManager);
            notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
        }
    }                                                                                                                             

The function for getting the pending Intent
private static PendingIntent getFullScreenIntent(Context context, AlarmModel alarmModel) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("packageName", alarmModel.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("title", alarmModel.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("vibrationWithSound", alarmModel.getVibrationWithSound());
        intent.putExtra("vibrationOnly", alarmModel.getVibrationOnly());
        intent.putExtra("numberOfPlay", alarmModel.getNumberOfPlay());
        intent.putExtra("soundLevel", alarmModel.getSoundLevel());
        intent.putExtra("alarmTone", alarmModel.getAlarmTone());

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        );
    }        

                                                                                                      I can see in the logs that my activity get created and also can see that it gets destroyed. So instead of full screen Intent I get a simple notification.                                                                             here are the logs   

2024-08-29 03:51:27.660  6048-6048  leolog                  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        E  onCreate
2024-08-29 03:51:27.706  6048-6048  ConnectivityManager     alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.sendRequestForNetwork(ConnectivityManager.java:4402)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallbackForUid(ConnectivityManager.java:4966)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4933)] [android.net.ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:4907)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver$FrameworkConnectivityMonitorPostApi24.register(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:188)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver.maybeRegisterReceiver(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:110)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver.register(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:91)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.register(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java:25)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.onStart(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java:34)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStart(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:51)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStart(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:203)] [androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3162)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2902)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:274)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:359)] [androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)] [android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1455)] [android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8315)] [android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:4060)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)] [android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)]
2024-08-29 03:51:27.719  6048-6109  SessionLifecycleClient  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Sending lifecycle 1 to service
2024-08-29 03:51:27.719  6048-6622  SessionLifecycleService alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Activity foregrounding at 442963470.
2024-08-29 03:51:27.722  6048-6048  leolog                  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        E  onResume
2024-08-29 03:51:27.735  6048-6048  DecorView               alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  notifyKeepScreenOnChanged: keepScreenOn=true
2024-08-29 03:51:27.749  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@1fb848 TM=true
2024-08-29 03:51:27.760  6048-6048  leolog                  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        E  onPause
2024-08-29 03:51:27.767  6048-6096  SessionLifecycleClient  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Sending lifecycle 2 to service
2024-08-29 03:51:27.767  6048-6622  SessionLifecycleService alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Activity backgrounding at 442963518
2024-08-29 03:51:27.872  6048-6048  BufferQueueConsumer     alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [](id:17a000000002,api:0,p:-1,c:6048) connect: controlledByApp=false
2024-08-29 03:51:27.876  6048-6048  BLASTBufferQueue        alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [ViewRootImpl@1fb1954[AlarmActivity]#2] constructor()
2024-08-29 03:51:27.881  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=14 res=0x7 s={true -5476376626004983808} ch=true fn=-1
2024-08-29 03:51:27.883  6048-6493  BufferQueueProducer     alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [ViewRootImpl@1fb1954[AlarmActivity]#2(BLAST Consumer)2](id:17a000000002,api:1,p:6048,c:6048) connect: api=1 producerControlledByApp=true
2024-08-29 03:51:27.884  6048-6493  OpenGLRenderer          alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  eglCreateWindowSurface
2024-08-29 03:51:27.896  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [DP] dp(1) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.reportNextDraw:11420 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4193 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:2919 
2024-08-29 03:51:27.896  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Creating frameDrawingCallback nextDrawUseBlastSync=false reportNextDraw=true hasBlurUpdates=false
2024-08-29 03:51:27.896  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Creating frameCompleteCallback
2024-08-29 03:51:27.921  6048-6625  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Received frameDrawingCallback frameNum=1. Creating transactionCompleteCallback=false
2024-08-29 03:51:27.942  6048-6493  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  Received frameCompleteCallback  lastAcquiredFrameNum=1 lastAttemptedDrawFrameNum=1
2024-08-29 03:51:27.946  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$addFrameCompleteCallbackIfNeeded$3$ViewRootImpl:4995 android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda16.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
2024-08-29 03:51:27.946  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  [DP] rdf()
2024-08-29 03:51:27.946  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  reportDrawFinished (fn: -1) 
2024-08-29 03:51:28.065  6048-6048  ViewRootIm...mActivity] alert.buzz.notification.alarm        I  stopped(true) old=false
2024-08-29 03:51:28.083  6048-6048  ConnectivityManager     alert.buzz.notification.alarm        D  StackLog: [android.net.ConnectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.java:5076)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver$FrameworkConnectivityMonitorPostApi24.unregister(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:202)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver.maybeUnregisterReceiver(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:119)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SingletonConnectivityReceiver.unregister(SingletonConnectivityReceiver.java:102)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.unregister(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java:29)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.DefaultConnectivityMonitor.onStop(DefaultConnectivityMonitor.java:39)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onStop(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:58)] [com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onStop(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:209)] [androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStop(Fragment.java:3321)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.stop(FragmentStateManager.java:639)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:299)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStop(FragmentManager.java:2919)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStop(FragmentController.java:307)] [androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:374)] [androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:257)] [android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1496)] [android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:8536)] [android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:5705)] [android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5649)] [android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:5750)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:234)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)] [android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)] [android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)]
2024-08-29 03:51:28.105  6048-6048  leolog                  alert.buzz.notification.alarm        E  onDestroy                                                                                                                

and I also aquire the wake lock in my activity onCreate
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                "app:AlarmWakeLock");
        wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /*10 minutes*/);type here

and for more clearity here is my manifest as well for the activity
  <activity
            android:name="com.example.messagealarm.AlarmActivity.AlarmActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AllApps" />

I think I have explained my question very well but still if you guys got any guys please let me know.
